# In DevExpress Template Gallery, XAF Controllers do not appear

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, xaf

In DevExpress Template Gallery (version `21.1`), XAF Controllers do not appear.
I use `.NET 5` and Visual Studio Pro version `16.11.2`

How can I fix this problem?

[image]

There are not XAF Controllers when I want to use them.
(I have tested in *.win, `*.Module.win` and in `*.Module`)

[image]

TimeReport.Win.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ApplicationIcon>ExpressApp.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.*</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="Controllers\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="Controllers\**" />
    <None Remove="Controllers\**" />
    <Page Remove="Controllers\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Model.xafml" />
    <None Remove="Images\Logo.svg" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Model.xafml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="Images\Logo.svg" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp" Version="21.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Security.Xpo" Version="21.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Validation.Win" Version="21.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Win" Version="21.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.ExpressApp.Xpo" Version="21.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Persistent.Base" Version="21.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.Persistent.BaseImpl" Version="21.1.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExpress.RichEdit.Export" Version="21.1.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TimeReport.Module.Win\TimeReport.Module.Win.csproj">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TimeReport.Module\TimeReport.Module.csproj">
      <Private>True</Private>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="TimeReportORMDataModel.xpo.diagram">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've ran into this issues and found out that this is a known issue with the 21.1.5 installer. There is a hotfix available:

[Core - XAF templates are not available in the Template Gallery for XAF Blazor projects](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1020723/core-xaf-templates-are-not-available-in-the-template-gallery-for-xaf-blazor-projects)